# Slow internet when connected to VPN and local SSH at the same time

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn

I use Surfshark VPN over the wireguard protocol with a dedicated IP. The connection is generally fine and the speed is not noticeably different with/without the VPN connected. However, if I ssh into another machine on my local network while the VPN is active, the internet connection becomes extremely slow. For example, pages take 30s plus to load or fail completely, video calls connect for a few seconds then lag out etc.

Another weird side affect I have noticed is that running a git fetch/pull on the ssh-host machine is extremely slow, but works fine if the VPN of the ssh-client machine is disconnected. This is particularly strange to me because my understanding was that the ssh-host machine should be using its own internet connection for any requests, independent of how the ssh-client machine is connected to the internet.

I have done some googling and general looking around, and I think the issue may be related to routing, but I have no experience in that area. Any help on where to begin troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for the suggestion. My upload is 200mbit/s, so unfortunately I don't think this is the issue.